# Add new partition under raid-1 array

Tags: partitioning, shell, centos, raid-1, fdisk

I have small /tmp partition, and I want to create new partition with size 10 GB than current one, I have two hard disk on raid-1 array

```
# mdadm --query --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Sat May 26 19:45:25 2012
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 33553344 (32.00 GiB 34.36 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 33553344 (32.00 GiB 34.36 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Nov 13 05:09:09 2012
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 95977b4c:6be67738:776c2c25:004bd7b2
         Events : 0.400

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

How could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you to using LVM http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/, that'll let you manage your partitions on the fly.

Else you need to create new md device for that partition.

Or shrink md0 and create another http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-resize-raid-partitions-shrink-and-grow-software-raid